# How to call to the copy constructor from the copy-assignment operator?

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I'm implementing a linked list. I wrote a copy constructor:

```
        // --- copy constructor ---
    IntList(const IntList& last_list) {
        first = new IntNode(last_list.getFirst()->getData());
        cout << "copy first " << first->getData() << endl;

        IntNode* last_node = first;
        IntNode* node = last_list.getFirst()->getNext();
        while(node!=NULL) {
            IntNode* new_node = new IntNode(node->getData());
            last_node->setNext(new_node);
            cout << "copy " << new_node->getData()<< endl;
            last_node = new_node;
            node = node->getNext();
        }
    }
```

As I understand, my copy-assignment operator (`operator=`) should have 2 goals:

- delete the current list.
- copy the new list.

I can achieve this 2 goals by calling the destructor which I already wrote and then call the copy constructor. How can I do it?

Comment: What's an assignment constructor?

Comment: Its copy assignment operator you mean. And AFAIK, you can't define this in terms of the copy constructor.

Comment: @MikeVine: sure you can.  The common Copy-and-swap for copy assignemtn works via the copy constructor

Comment: I see that you have edited your post, but the point of my parenthesis was not to replace "assignment" with "copy-assignment", but to replace "constructor" with "operator"... (Besides, the "copy assignment operator" is often simply called the "assignment operator". The "copy" prefix just adds precision: e.g. for `std::string`, both `string& operator=(const string&)` and `string& operator=(const char*)` are assignment operators, but only the first is a _copy_ assignment operator, because the argument is of the same type as the class. It's a parallel to constructors and _copy_ constructor.)

Answer (score 9):

For your *copy assignment operator*, you can use the **[copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) idiom**.

For example in your case, you could add this into your `IntList` class definition (given the code of your copy constructor, I'm assuming that your only data member is `IntNode* first;`):

```
        // --- swap non-member function ---
    friend void swap(IntList& a, IntList& b) /* no-fail */ {
        // swap data members one by one
        std::swap(a.first, b.first);
    }

        // --- (copy) assignment operator ---
    IntList& operator=(const IntList& other) {
        IntList temp(other); // copy construction
        swap(*this, temp);   // swap
        return *this;
                             // destruction of temp ("old *this")
    }
```

Actually, this may be better style:

```
        // --- swap non-member function ---
    friend void swap(IntList& a, IntList& b) /* no-fail */ {
        using std::swap; // enable ADL
        // swap data members one by one
        swap(a.first, b.first);
    }

        // --- (copy) assignment operator ---
    IntList& operator=(IntList other) { // note: take by value
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
```

The `/* no-fail */` comment can be replaced with `throw()` (or maybe just a `/* throw() */` comment) in C++98/03, `noexcept` in C++11.

(Note: Don't forget to beforehand include the right header for [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), that is, `<algorithm>` in C++98/03, `<utility>` in C++11 (you can as well include both).)

Remark: Here the `swap` function is defined in the class body but it is nevertheless a *non-member* function because it is a `friend`.

See the linked post for the whole story.

(Of course, you must also provide a correct *destructor* definition in addition to your copy constructor (see [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).)

Comment: Please elaborate a bit in your answer instead of just linking to a different post.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have updated my answer with concrete code. (But the linked post remains a must-read.)

Answer (score 1):

Put the functionality you need in separate functions called by the destructor and the copy constructor and the assignment operator.